# How to do relative imports in Python without sys.path.append neither -m falg neither with __init__.py file?

Tags: python, python-import

I know that python mechanism doesn't allow doing relative imports without a known parent package, but I want to know which the reason is.

If relative imports worked without known parent package it would make developers life much easier (I think, correct me if I am wrong)

### Example:

From a python script a have to import a global definitions file. Right now I have to do it like this:

```
DEFS_PATH = '../../../'
sys.path.append(DEFS_PATH)
import DEFINITIONS as defs
```

If I could import this file just like this without having to specify the `-m` flag when executing the script or creating a `__init__.py` file that collects all packages. It would make everything much more easier.

```
from .... import DEFINITIONS as defs
```

Of course doing this raises the famous import error:
[image: import error]

Obviously this is a toy example, but **imagine having to repeat this in hundreds of python scripts**...

Is there any workaround for **importing relative packages** without a known parent package that doesn't involve tha hacky ugly way (`sys.path.append(...)` or `python -m myscript` )?

Comment: "WHY does X happen?" and "Is there a workaround for X?" are two completely different questions (and the first one is [often off-topic here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170415/144918)).

Comment: Make the parent package known. Just put an `__init__.py` file in every package and subpackage.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you Charles, just edited the question

Comment: @Seth yeah I know, but is there another way that doesn't involve doing repetitive `__init__.py` files? Just edited the question

Comment: The requirement for `__init__.py` files in anything that's supposed to be considered a Python package strikes me as _extremely_ well-founded; otherwise you could have searches going off into completely unrelated parts of the directory tree. And remember, not all Python modules exist in on-disk directories at all; the boundary conditions get weird. What do you expect to happen when something is imported from an egg or a zip file and it uses `..` to get out of it? Better to just refuse than to risk doing the unexpected.

Comment: The point is why are you  using a relative import for that module if it doesn't have a common parent package? Also have you ever thought that if this constraint wasn't present one could simply import from **anywhere** in the user's file system? It would increase the chances of bugs and also a potential vulnerability.

Comment: ..."in the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess" is part of the Zen of Python. Scanning parts of the filesystem that aren't explicitly Python packages is very much guessing. If you don't have a `__init__.py` file, your directory is not part of a package, _period_.

Comment: If your script has these external dependencies, then just package it up so it can be installed with pip. Why are you trying to avoid doing it the proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem but in a different way. I have a folder where I have lots of global functions that I used in different packages, I could create a Python Package of this folder, however I would have to rebuild it each time I changed something.

The solution that fitted me was to add `user-packages.pth` file in `site-packages` directory of my current environment, but it could also be added to global `site-packages` folder. Inside this `user-packages.pth` I added the absolute path to my directory where all the global utils are. And now I just have to do from any python script

```
from utils import data_processing as dp
from utils.database import database_connection as dc
```

Now I don't need to add in each file sys.path.append("path/to/myutils/")

---

Note:

The `.pth` file could have any file name (`customName.pth`) and paths inside the file should be separated by carriage return ("\n"). Also, paths should be absoulte.

For example:

```
C:\path\to\utils1
C:\path\to\other\utils2
```